# Failed to convert @drawable/ into a drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have added an image to my Android project which I want to use in the UI. I have added the file *my-image.png* to the *drawable* directory (to all 4 drawable directories created with the project), and added the `ImageView` to the layout:

```xml
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:src="@drawable/my-image" />
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

> Rendering Problems
>
> Failed to convert @drawable/my-image into a drawable

This is the capture:

[image]

Additionaly, if I try to compile the project, I get the following error:

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyProject:processDebugResources'.

Why do I get these errors and how can I solve it? Am I missing something? I've just started Android development.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyProject:processDebugResources'.
```

because you have naming convention error in Resources

```
file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

Rename file name to `my_image`

Answer (score 5):

Try using underscore and small characters in file name, for example

my_image.png

Answer (score 5):

```
Rename this drawable @drawable/my-image to @drawable/my_image
```

Answer (score 2):

Try To use only abc...xyz and 0123...9, dont use -, instead use _(underscore).

Use `my_name` instead of `my-name`, because Hyphens(-) have a special meaning in coding, so it cant be use literally with strings.

Comment: What reason is there to avoid hyphens in strings?

Comment: Stay away from numbers as well, resources cannot begin with numbers

Answer (score 0):

If the naming convention is correct try:

Open up resources dialog and see if image png preview is displayed.

> Select image in design view > Go to properties > Click the ellipsis button > Drawable > Search for your png image and click on it.

If the preview is not displayed cancel out of resources, and try resaving the image again in png format.

> This example uses photoshop CS2. Open image in photoshop and select **Files > Save For Web > Click Save**. (Do not use File > Save As)

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me you should not include special characters only alphabets